# How to add event to input in Angular 5 app using directive?

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-directive

I have the following directive `groupingFormat` which perform grouping to an input text
when user use the key up:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[groupingFormat]'
})
export class GroupingFormatDirective {

  private el: HTMLInputElement;  
  constructor(elRef: ElementRef) {
    this.el = elRef.nativeElement;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    let elem : HTMLInputElement = this.el; 
     elem.addEventListener('keyup',() => { 
      this.el.value = this.digitGrouping(this.el.value);
     });
   }
}
```

Example of usage:

```
<input type="text" #myValue="ngModel" name="my_value" [(ngModel)]="myObj.myValue" id="my_value" required groupingFormat>
```

This directive is working as expected but now I have new requirement: The input
text should use the directive also when the page is load and also if the a form
is open inside the page with the input becoming visible.

Is there an easy way to update the directive to support this functionality or
any alternative solution? Attach another directive ?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by input text should use directive?

Comment: The directive is not working when the form is visible that's all because I have only event for keyup.

Comment: Did you tried using hostlistener decorator?

Comment: no, if you think that's the solution for the problem can you try answer the question? thanks

Comment: Already answered by @Kshitij Try That

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input type="text" name="my_value" [appInputevent]="myValue" [(ngModel)]="myValue">
```

directive file

```
import { Directive,HostListener,ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appInputevent]'
})
export class InputeventDirective {

  constructor(private el:ElementRef) { }

  @Input('appInputevent') params: string;

 @HostListener('keyup', ['$event'])
  onKeyUp(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log('got parameters: '+this.params);
  }

  private highlight(color: string) {
    this.el.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }

}
```

change hostlistner event according to your need.

For demonstration-- https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic2-test?file=app%2Finputevent.directive.ts

Comment: I've tried this solution and I'm getting now: Can't bind to 'appInputevent' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Comment: i have added link for demonstration. check only for InputeventDirective, as there is one more directive.

Comment: I've removed the brackets [] and now no errors, but It doesn't work.

Comment: don't remove bracket. check if you have imported directive properly. have you went thorough the link?

Comment: myvalue variable needs to be declared also.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, nowit works I mean the keyup work, but I need to do logic when the input is displayed. Any idea which event is that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189500/discussion-between-kshitij-tiwari-and-user2304483).